# Store multiple values in a checkbox to check with php

Tags: php, html, css, checkbox

I have this school assignment of making an comparison site between mc and bk.

Now I have this:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />

     </head>
     <?php

     if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
         {
             $breakfastMC = $_POST['BreakfastMC'];
             $breakfastBK = $_POST['BreakfastBK'];
             $sumMC = 0;
             $sumBK = 0;
             if(empty($breakfastMC)) 
                 {
                     echo("<p>You didn't select any food in MC.</p>\n");
                 } 
             else 
                 {
                     $MC = count($breakfastMC);

                     echo("<p>You selected for MC = $MC:<br/>");
                     for($i=0; $i < $MC; $i++)
                         {   
                             echo( "Price = " . $breakfastMC[$i] . "<br/>");
                             $sumMC += floatval( $breakfastMC[$i] );
                         }
                     echo "Total MC = " . $sumMC . "<br/>";
                 }
             if(empty($breakfastBK)) 
                 {
                     echo("<p>You didn't select any food in BK.</p>\n");
                 } 
             else 
                 {
                     $BK = count($breakfastBK);

                     echo("<p>You selected for BK = $BK:<br/>");
                     for($i=0; $i < $BK; $i++)
                         {
                             echo( "Price = " . $breakfastBK[$i] . "<br/>");
                             $sumBK += floatval( $breakfastBK[$i] );
                         }
                     echo "Total BK = " . $sumBK . "<br/>";
                 }
             //$sumBK = array_sum($BK)       
             //$sumMC = array_sum($MC)
             if ( $sumBK == $sumMC )
                 echo 'equal';
             else if ( $sumBK > $sumMC )
                 echo 'BK more expensive than MC';
             else echo 'MC more expensive than BK';


             function IsChecked($chkname,$value)
             {
                 if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
                     {
                         foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
                             {
                                 if($chkval == $value)
                                     {
                                         return true;
                                     }
                             }
                     }
                 return false;
             }
         }
     ?>


     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <div class="MC">
     <h2><b>Mc Donalds</b></h2>
     <br />
     <b>Ontbijt:</b>
     <br />

     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]" id="squaredOne1"   value="2"/>
     <label for="squaredOne1"></label>
     <div class="McText">Croissant jam en boter Prijs = 2       Cal = 100</div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne2"   value="3"/>
     <label for="squaredOne2"></label>
     <div class="McText">Pancakes met stroop <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne3"   value="3"/>
     <label for="squaredOne3"></label>
     <div class="McText">McMuffin met Bacon en Ei <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne4"   value="4"/>
     <label for="squaredOne4"></label>
     <div class="McText">McMuffin met Kaas <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne5"   value="2"/>
     <label for="squaredOne5"></label>
     <div class="McText">2x Versgemalen koffie <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne6"   value="2"/>
     <label for="squaredOne6"></label>
     <div class="McText">2x Thee <br /></div>
     </div>
     <b>Lunch:</b>
     <br />
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC[]" id="squaredOne7"   value="2"/>
     <label for="squaredOne7"></label>
     <div class="McText">Hamburger <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC[]" id="squaredOne8"   value="3"/>
     <label for="squaredOne8"></label>
     <div class="McText">Cheeseburger <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC[]" id="squaredOne9"   value="4"/>
     <label for="squaredOne9"></label>
     <div class="McText">1955 met bacon <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC[]" id="squaredOne10"   value="3"/>
     <label for="squaredOne10"></label>
     <div class="McText">McKroket <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne11"   value="2"/>
     <label for="squaredOne11"></label>
     <div class="McText">Coca Cola Middel (0,4L) <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne12"   value="4"/>
     <label for="squaredOne12"></label>
     <div class="McText">Coca Cola Groot (0,5L) <br /></div>
     </div>

     <b>Avondeten:</b>
     <br />
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC[]" id="squaredOne13"   value="4"/>
     <label for="squaredOne13"></label>
     <div class="McText">Big Mac <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC[]" id="squaredOne14"   value="3"/>
     <label for="squaredOne14"></label>
     <div class="McText">Chicken Sensation <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC[]" id="squaredOne15"   value="5"/>
     <label for="squaredOne15"></label>
     <div class="McText">Chili Chicken <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC[]" id="squaredOne16"   value="4"/>
     <label for="squaredOne16"></label>
     <div class="McText">Big Tasty met bacon <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne17"   value="5"/>
     <label for="squaredOne17"></label>
     <div class="McText">Coca Cola Mega (0,7L) <br /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne18"   value="4"/>
     <label for="squaredOne18"></label>
     <div class="McText">Coca Cola Groot (0,5L) <br /></div>
     </div>

     <br />

     </div>

     <div class="BK">

     <h2><b>Burger King </b></h2>

     <b>Ontbijt:</b>
     <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="1.50">  Mini Pancakes (9stuks) €1,50 364kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="1.50">  Toastie €1,50 359 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="3.00">  Breakfast Burger €3,00  825 kcal <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.75">  Breakfast Wrap €2,75 441 kcal<br /> <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="3.80">  2xKoffie €3,80 0 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.25">  1 flesje Chaudfontaine (500 ml) €2,25 0 kcal<br />

     <b>Lunch:</b>
     <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK[]"   value="4.55">  Grilled Chicken Wrap €4,55  344 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK[]"   value="1.95">  Cheeseburger €1,95 338 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK[]"   value="5.75">  Tripple Whopper €5,75  1114 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK[]"   value="4.75">  Big King XXL  €4,75 1022 kcal<br /> <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.00">  Coca Cola M (400 ml)  €2,00 168 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.50">  Coca Cola XXL (750 ml) €2,50  315 kcal<br />

     <b>Avondeten:</b>
     <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK[]"   value="4.75">  Double Cheeseburger XXL  €4,75  502 kcal <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK[]"   value="5.25">  Grilled Chicken BBQ €5,25 707 kcal<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK[]"   value="3.25">  Whopper Jr. €3,25 362 kcal  <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK[]"   value="3.75">  Big King €3,75 552 kcal <br /> <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.25">  Coca Cola M (400 ml) €2,25 210 kcal <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.50">  Coca Cola XXL (750 ml) €2,50  315 kcal<br />

     </div>
     <div class="Button">
     <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit">
     </div>


     </form>

     </body>
     </html>
```

This code compares the values from MC and BK but only the price. Is it possible to somehow add like a value2 to a checkbox for the calories, so they get compared as well?

Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]" value1="10" value2="20"/>
```

Or any other way?

this is the site btw: http://informaticaphp.net84.net/home.php
[warning: possibly compromised]

Comment: What are all those `<======` comments for?

Comment: An input can only send one value. You could put `value="10-20"`, and then the PHP code can split it up.

Comment: Okay, and how would I do this without messing up all my code :s

Comment: A better way is to not put the prices and calories in the value at all. Just put an identifier for each product, and use an array in the PHP to look up the price and calories.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? or maybe link me to something because I don't really get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put the price in the value, just put an identifier for the product there, e.g.

```
 <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]" id="squaredOne1"   value="croissant"/>
 <label for="squaredOne1"></label>
 <div class="McText">Croissant jam en boter Prijs = 2       Cal = 100</div>
 </div>
 <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne2"   value="pancakes"/>
 <label for="squaredOne2"></label>
 <div class="McText">Pancakes met stroop <br /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne3"   value="mcmuffinbacon"/>
 <label for="squaredOne3"></label>
 <div class="McText">McMuffin met Bacon en Ei <br /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"  id="squaredOne4"   value="mcmuffinkaas"/>
 <label for="squaredOne4"></label>
 <div class="McText">McMuffin met Kaas <br /></div>
 </div>
```

Use an array to map the product IDs to the price and calories:

```
$MCmenu = array('croissant' => array('price' => 2, 'calories' => 100),
                'pancakes' => array('price' => 3, 'calories' => 200),
                'mcmuffinbacon' => array('price' => 3, 'calories' => 450),
                'mcmuffinkaas' => array('price' => 4, 'calories' => 350),
                ...);
$BKmenu = array('pancakes' => array('price' => 1.5, 'calories' => 364),
                'toastie' => array('price' => 1.5, 'calories' => 359),
                'breakfastburger' => array('price' => 3, 'calories' => 825),
                ...);
```

Then when you're calculating the price, you can do:

```
 foreach($breakfastMC AS $bk)
     {
         echo( "Price = " . $MCmenu[$bk]['price'] . "<br/>");
         echo( "Calories = " . $MCmenu[$bk]['calories'] . "<br/>");
         $sumMC += $MCmenu[$bk]['price'];
         $caloriesMC += $MCmenu[$bk]['calories'];

     }
```

To further improve this, you can put descriptions in the menu arrays

```
$MCmenu = array('croissant' => array('price' => 2, 'calories' => 100, 'desc' => 'Croissant jam en boter Prijs'),
                'pancakes' => array('price' => 3, 'calories' => 200, desc => 'Pancakes met stroop'),
                'mcmuffinbacon' => array('price' => 3, 'calories' => 450, 'desc' => 'McMuffin met Bacon en Ei')
                ...);
```

Then you can generate the HTML from this:

```
foreach ($MCmenu as $id => $item) {
    $price = $item['price'];
    $cal = $item['calories'];
    $desc = $item['desc'];
    ?>
 <div class="squaredOne"><input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]" id="BreakfastMC<?php echo $id ?>"   value="<?php echo $id ?>"/>
 <label for="BreakfastMC<?php echo $id ?>"></label>
 <div class="McText"><?php echo $desc ?> = <?php echo $price ?>       Cal = <?php echo $cal ?></div>
 </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Okay thanks you, but how do I make the MCmenu array read the values from the checkbox?

Comment: The MCMenu array doesn't get the values from the checkbox. You have to put all the values in the script.

Comment: What you could do is put all the descriptions in the array. Then you can generate all the HTML from the arrays. That way you don't have to repeat the prices and calories in both places.

Comment: :o that would be usefull, how would I do that?

Comment: I've added it to the answer.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that the php gets executed when I click the submit button so you see nothing at first right?

Comment: The code that displays the menu shouldn't be in the `if(isset)` block, so it will be executed when you load the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78726/discussion-between-stangaming-666-and-barmar).